# Link to custom page with DataFormWebPart from Sharepoint 2010 search results

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search-results, data-form-web-part

I have custom page which uses given in url id parameter and DataFormWebPart to represent item from custom list.

When I do search for any item from this list I get link to standard display form.

How can I make that each item from the list is searched and shown only in my custom page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to make search results pointing to custom presentation is to move the presentation from custom page to a new list item display form and setting it to be a default display form.